# Only when the left button is pressed, the player moves left and does not stop

Tags: flash

this is the code for my game. I'm using Flash Develop to code it because I find it easier in flash develop.

When I press right, up, and down my player moves according the to the directions. But when the left arrow key is pressed the player moves to the left and does not stop.

```
    package  
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
/**
 * ...
 * @author Moynul Hussain
 */
public class main extends MovieClip
{
    //MainMenu

    //background
    public var back:MovieClip;

    public var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var upPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var downPressed:Boolean = false;

    public var xScrollSpeed:int = 10;
    public var yScrollSpeed:int = 10;



    public var mcPlayButton:MovieClip;

    public function main() 
    {


    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);


    }

    private function loop(e:Event):void 
    {
        if (leftPressed)
        {
            back.x += xScrollSpeed;
        } 
        else if (rightPressed)
        {
            back.x -= xScrollSpeed;
        }

        if (upPressed) 
        {   
        back.y += yScrollSpeed;

        } 
        else if (downPressed)
        {
            back.y -= yScrollSpeed;
        }   
    }



    function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
        if (e.keyCode == 37)
        {
        trace("left pressed");
        leftPressed = true;

        } 
        else if (e.keyCode == 39 )
        {
        trace("right pressed");
        rightPressed = true;

        } else if(e.keyCode == 38){
        trace("up pressed");
        upPressed = true;

        } else if(e.keyCode == 40){
        trace("down pressed");
        downPressed = true;
        }
        }

    function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
        if(e.keyCode == 37){
        trace("left released");
        upPressed = false;

        } else if(e.keyCode == 39){
        trace("right released");
        rightPressed = false;

        } else if(e.keyCode == 38){
        trace("up released");
        upPressed = false;

        } else if(e.keyCode ==40){
        trace("down released");
        downPressed = false;
        }
        }


   }

 }
```

I'm very sorry if my coding irritates any one, I copy and paste from Flash Develop to here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got it set to release the up key:

```
if(e.keyCode == 37){
trace("left released");  // left
upPressed = false;       // up
}
```